# Ignoring arrow keys when using the select menu with readline

Tags: bash, backspace, arrow-keys

I have written a bash script that looks like this which basically handles user operation based on selection.

```
PS3='Please enter current status of the completion: '
    boolean_status=("completed" "not-yet")
    select opt in "${boolean_status[@]}"
    do
       if [ "$REPLY" -ge 1 -a "$REPLY" -le 2 ]; then   
        n=$opt
        break;
       fi
    done
```

But I am facing a problem with this code snippet the input of this code accepts `backspace as ^H` and `up as [[A^` etc. I want my user to use up and down arrows freely without these symbols popping up. Is there a way to resolve this issue.

Like in the `read` command we have `-e` option that neglects all these characters what is it's equivalent in select??

Comment: Seems you'll need a select replacement that uses readline.

Comment: @DanD. Ok, but how can I use readline here??

Comment: [Write your own select](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203327/74329). Replace there `read -p '#? ' opt` with `read -e -p '#? ' opt` to use readline.

Comment: @KNDheeraj: did the answer help you out?

Comment: @Inian actually I tried cyrus's solution and it was working fine, so didn't test your solution!!